# Smartsheet custom attachmentType

Tags: smartsheet-api

Is it possible to add custom attachment type that is displayed in the dropdown menu and provides custom attachment creation process?

I've quickly looked over API Documentation and I found some methods with which I can download/upload attachments through API calls.

But I didn't found any info how I could integrate my custom attachment process into regular smartsheet workflow.

Comment: post essential code with comment where you want to include this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for a way to extend the list of options that the Smartsheet user interface (UI) shows for uploading an attachment (by adding your own custom option to that list). Is that correct?

[image]

If that's what you're looking to do, then unfortunately that's not possible. You can't use the API to change UI components of the Smartsheet application itself.

Comment: That is correct, I wanted to extend this with screen clipping app.
Thanks for the answer.